# Is it OK to significantly change content of a question after it has been answered

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I asked  [this question about transporting twins](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/468/recommendations-for-transporting-twins-on-the-front-of-a-bike) a few weeks back. The original thrust of the question was how to transport twins without a trailer. There are several good answers for both putting kids on the bike and in a trailer (which is changing my opinion on using a trailer).

I think now that it would be better to change the question to ask a general 'how to transport twins' - i.e. convert the question to match the answers. And I think this because it would make the question more useful to a broader range of people.

Is it OK to do this ?  I've made it a CW question, so anyone can change it.

Comment: One factor is the "transport twins without a trailer" is a more interesting question, so more lickly to be clicked on by someone going a google search.  I don't know how inportant this is.

Comment: I agree with Ian, I'd rather see more interesting questions than fewer, more general questions. Fortunately, there's room for both. In a general sense, one can also post more than one question about the same topic.

Answer (score 4):

I would be fine with it, with the reservation that you make it obvious in the question that you've changed it and why. The fact that the answers have changed what you're looking for means that you got some good answers.

Others may disagree.

Edit: After thinking about this, I'm going to add that the original question was interesting and unique in my experience. You can't be the only parent who thinks that their child in a trailer -- where you can't see them -- seems unnerving and dangerous.

Answer (score 4):

Yes -- this is encouraged, as the slightly more general (without becoming *absurdly* general, obviously) form of the question is more inclusive and can be more canonical.

See:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/

> **It is OK to edit a question to make it more general.**
>
> With the power of editing comes the power to take someone’s selfish, very specific question, and edit it a little bit until they’re asking the more general question that hundreds of people encounter. For example, if someone asks, “I set up a web server at home but I can’t access it from work,” it’s OK to rewrite the question as, “What things should I check when a web server running at home is not visible on the Internet?” In fact, sometimes selfish, stupid questions of the “do my homework” variety can be easily edited into a form where the answer will provide an extremely valuable resource for the internet at large.